# Is it ok to use asserts in production code (not in test suite) to ensure expected behaviour

Tags: rust

I notice when reading the docs that they often use `assert` when explaining expected behaviour of simple code blocks.

In production level code, would it be considered an anti-pattern to do the same? While reading rust by example I only saw assert's being used in tests, but in the instances where you do expect vars or values to be a *specific thing*, is assert the correct approach?

The example I came across in my own code is a scenario similar to the following...

```rust
fn foo(values: Vec<String>, my_num: usize) {
    assert_eq!(values.len(), my_num);
    // run this code after
}
```

I expect the vector passed to have a length equal to another value in the function, and the code wouldn't work if that wasn't the case. Would asserting these two values as being equal be the correct practice?

What are some other best practices or ways of handling other error behaviour?

Comment: See [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html)/[`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html)

Comment: If you haven't read [Error Handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) in the Rust Book, I suggest you do.

Comment: [Assertions for run-time checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)#Assertions_for_run-time_checking) have been a thing for a long time to detect unrecoverable conditions. Though you should try to recover the error instead of halting.

Comment: Do it if you need this to enforce some memory-safety related invariant. Standard library is filled with those assertions (for example when indexing an array).

Comment: I'm not the expert at the "Rust" programming language, but I'd say the question is the same as: Should I use if statements to assert conditions in tests?  The answer is no.  You build code, then you build tests to assert that code works.  I can't tell you why exactly you shouldn't use assert, but it's like if statements over switch cases.  You technically CAN use an if/if else statement chain 10 clauses deep, but you should really use a switch.

Comment: It would not be a proper error handling since the assertion will make the thread panic in case of failing, just like calling  `unwrap` on a `Result` for example, which you should avoid as much as possible in production. Catch and handle the error is always better if possible. But if panic is the expected behavior in this case then why not using an assertion I guess..

Comment: "Would asserting these two values as being equal be the correct practice?" to me it seems iffy, assertions certainly have their place in Rust (e.g. that's basically what you get when indexing a slice/vec out of bounds using Index), but without more context it seems difficult to know whether it's more suitable than returning a proper `Result`, or finding a way to encode this relationship such that it holds by construction. It's certainly not the first resort.

Comment: The issue is that your example is so simplistic that it is trivially solved: `my_num` is worthless, just remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Assertions are OK in unsafe code. For example, if you need to ensure that a pointer is non-null. Otherwise, it’s better to use Results, Options and usual conditions.

```rust
struct FooError;

fn foo(values: Vec<String>, my_num: usize) -> Result<(), FooError> {
    if values.len() != my_num {
        return Err(FooError);
    }
    …
    Ok(())

}
```